# Library to convert a Japanese sentence to kana in C#?

Tags: c#, kana

Is there any library in C# suport converting a Japanese sentence to kana?

e.g. `私はスポーツが好きです。` --> `わたしはスポーツがすきです。`

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a article on CodeProject: [How to Convert between Romaji and Hiragana/Katakana](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/792588/How-to-Convert-between-Romaji-and-Hiragana-Katakan)

and a question here: [Hiragana to Kanji converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089798/hiragana-to-kanji-converter)